# How can i change the permissions of dynamically created Tags through REST API in Splunk?

Tags: api, rest, permissions, tags, splunk

I am creating tags through REST endpoints,but the permission of the tags are private.To make them public,Is there any Endpoint services available through which i can change the permissions of tags which i have created.
Currently i tried using this url  with POST request with following data but it didn't work out for me https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/tags/tag_name/acl -d sharing="app" -d perms.write="*" -d perms.read="*"

Any help is appreciated.I am currently using Splunk version 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer finally :
You can update the permission of tags through REST API having a POST request at the following url and parameters:

[https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/ks/search/saved/fvtags/tag_name/field%3Dvalue/acl -d owner="ks" -d sharing="app" -d perms.read="*" -d perms.write="*"](https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/ks/search/saved/fvtags/tag_name/field%3Dvalue/acl%20-d%20owner=%22ks%22%20-d%20sharing=%22app%22%20-d%20perms.read=%22*%22%20-d%20perms.write=%22*%22)